# Deal with Emoji in C# and windows 7

Tags: c#

I was developing a chat application and It was working fine when my developing environment was windows 8. later I changed it to widows 7 and find out that there is some problem with recognizing emojies as string in C#. In windows 8 this code worked fine

```
if (text.EndsWith("❓")){
...
}
```

the input string was '❓21',but when I moved my solution into windows 7 this parts confuses and return true for '❓21' while it must return false, Also in debugs the ❓ is set as unknown charackter, I also searched and find that there is an update from Microsoft which adds Emojies support to windows 7 and I installed it but there is error yet. How can I deal with emojies now?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre thanks but how?

Comment: It's a compiler/IDE bug, Windows is not to blame.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev but the same visual studio is on both systems.

Comment: The compiler and IDE don't care about Emojis. It's just Unicode text to them. If the OS doesn't have that character though, it can't display it.

Comment: If you can't type the emoji directly, type its Unicode escape code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but How can I compare those unicode escape cods?for example how I fix the code in question?

Comment: That code should work fine (even without emoji support in the OS it should work though perhaps not displaying such strings well). My first suspicion would be the encoding the source file is in, and is assumed to be in by the compiler. Does saving it as utf8 with a BOM make any difference?

Comment: @MajidHojati just like any other string! They are just escape sequences. `"\u000a"=="\n"` is true. What is the escape sequence for this emoji?

Comment: @JonHanna How can I cnahe encoding of saved file?the was working on another system with windows 8 and I just moved solution to this new version

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Here it is U+2705

Comment: 2705 or 2753? Copying the symbol in the question it's 2753 and `"❓"=="\u2753"` returns true. 2705 is ✅

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes it was my mistake..thanks I'll try it new